# Set Session variable and prevent postback on ASP.NET button click

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP button that, when clicked, needs to set a session variable and run some javascript code to pop up a window.  I have this all working fine, however when this happens the main page does a postback and jumps back to the top of the page.  How can I prevent the postback and still set the session variable and call the javascript?  So that the main window stays in the same position?

Comment: Why are you using an ASP .NET button for this?  Just use a button.

Comment: Can you just set the information in a cookie? Then you can do it all in javascript and not worry about postback...

Comment: why do you want to use session variable? Can you explain a bit more

Comment: the button belongs on a profile page.  When clicked, it pops up a window with a list of cities.  It loads the cities that the profile already belongs to a session variable, at which time the pop up reads the session and checks off cities that already belong to the profile.  Then the user can go through selecting/unselecting cities and click save, closing the pop up and saving the selected list to the profile.  This all works great, but the client wants the page to stop posting them back to the top of the page.  They want to remain on the same place on the page when they're finished

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it with ajax, set ASP.NET button to run only on client, set onClient event to :

```
onclient="SetSession(); return false;"
```

and in SetSession() JavaScript function call server method, for example simple ashx, and if server call succeeded then you can call additional JavaScript you need.
(using jQuery it's much easier) :

```
function SetSession()
{
  jQuery.ajax({
                url: "SetServerSideSession.ashx", 
                success: function (data) 
                {  
                  AdditionalJavascript();
                }
             });
}
```

Comment: admittedly I'm not very familiar with ajax, or .ashx pages  how would I use this?

Comment: for what it's worth, the session variable needs to be set to text from a textbox

Answer (score 1):

To maintain same position after postback you can use Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack

[Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx)

Comment: I tried this, but it isn't working...perhaps something to do with master pages?

Comment: Try setting <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="True"> in your web.config - keep in mind though that it will affect your entire website